# Getting laravel app Database running on local

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys I'm new to PHP/Laravel, from a rails background.  I pulled down an app via ssh that has certain database configurations and I cant for the life of me get this app running locally these are the errors I keep getting.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'fatkikisManiak'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

For this error I noticed that it was trying to run the production configurations so I thought it best to change to a development config.  I went into bootstrap/start.php and

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

  \\'local' => array('homestead', 'Username', 'password'),
  'local' => array('MacBook-Pro'),

));
```

This gives me:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'fatkikis_local'

Any help on getting this resolved would be apprciated

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `.env` file in the root folder and modify the database informations.

This is a hidden file.

Comment: since the .env file wasn't checked in originally it wasnt included in the files that I pulled down.  I'll take a look to see what I can do with this. Thank you.

Comment: Ok @kóta-Péter so I created a new .env file however the database info is hard coded into the config/database.php file is the .env file still required?